# Semantic UI on dart

Tags: javascript, dart, semantic-ui

I want to use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/semantic_ui_for_pub but do not know how to include in the index.html and main.dart file.

Can someone please to me, how to do that?

Comment: I think the answer is going to involve JavaScript interop.

Comment: You don't need to include `index.html` anywhere. For `main.dart` add a script tag to `index.html`. With the `stagehand` package it's really easy to set up a new project. It also integrates with WebStorm and atom.

Comment: Please show an example. I am pretty new in dart and do not know how to use semantic ui

Comment: Example of what? Have you tried stagehand? Did you check any of the Dart tutorials at https://www.dartlang.org/ ?

Comment: Yes, I checked stagehand and create a web application but how to include semantic ui to my project. I want to use dropdown list from semantic ui. How to do that with dart?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer what should I do now? Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Yeah, you could make use of that stuff using the dart:js package, or you could just include it as straight JS and communicate with it through events (as detailed here: https://dart.academy/easy-dart-js-interopt). It depends on the structure of your application which approach is best.